# binary_search in c++ unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, stl

The following snippet is returning me 0. I expected it to be 1. What's wrong going on here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  vector<int> v;
  int arr[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
  v.push_back(11);
  v.push_back(22);
  copy(arr,arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]),back_inserter(v));  // back_inserter makes space starting from the end of vector v
  for(auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i){
    cout << *i << endl;
  }
  cout << endl << "Binary Search -  "  << binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 10) <<endl; // returns bool 
}
```

I am using gcc /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper

Comment: Does binary search require a sorted array? is `v` sorted?

Comment: could you post the output from your code? what do you get from the `cout` statements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran the program and saw this:

```
11
22
10
20
30
40
50

Binary Search -  0
```

Your array is not sorted, therefore, binary search fails. (it sees `11` in the first position, and concludes `10` does not exist here)

You either want to ensure the array is sorted before binary searching or use the regular `std::find`.

Comment: This is the answer. You cannot binary search an unsorted array.

Answer (score 4):

[`binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) says:

> Checks if the sorted range `[first, last)` contains an element equal to
>   `value`. The first version uses `operator<` to compare the elements, the
>   second version uses the given comparison function `comp`.

Your list is not sorted, it contains the elements `11` and `22` prior to `10`.

Answer (score 4):

Your array is not sorted, so `binary_search` got undefined behavior. Try `std::find` instead

```
bool found = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 10) != v.end()
```

§25.4.3.4 of the C++11 standard (3242 draft)

> 1. Requires: The elements e of [first,last) are partitioned with respect to the expressions e < value and !(value < e) or comp(e,
>      value) and !comp(value, e). Also, for all elements e of [first, last),
>      e < value implies !(value < e) or comp(e, value) implies !comp(value,
>      e).

Answer (score 4):

"Unexpected behavior"? There's nothing unexpected here.

The whole idea of binary search algorithm is taking advantage of the fact that the input array is *sorted*. If the array is not sorted, there can't be any binary search on it.

When you use `std::binary_search` (as well as all other standard binary search-based algorithms), the input sequence must be sorted in accordance with the same comparison predicate as the one used by `std::binary_search`. Since you did not pass any custom predicate to `std::binary_search`, it will use the ordering defined by `<` operator. That means that your input Sequence of integers must be sorted in ascending order.

In your case the input sequence does not satisfy that requirement. `std::binary_search` cannot be used on it.